# How to run two oracle instances in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

My Oracle have two instances(2 sid). From that, I can connect to one(A) instance via toad using service name. But another instance(B) is not connecting.

When I am trying to connect that instance, It is showing error like

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
```

I have noticed, my `ORACLE_SID` is pointing to A instance. I wanted two (A&B) instances available.

Please suggest what are the changes required. Actually Oracle installed in *Linux*.

Comment: Post the output of 1. `cat /etc/oratab` 2. `lsnrctl status` 3. `tnsping >sid2>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested steps to try and tackle the problem - 
1. Perform the test Balakumar Subramanian suggested to make sure your tnsnames is configured probably.
2. step 1 doesn't fix the problem, try connecting to the database from within the server by connecting as the user used to install oracle (usually oracle), setting the environment variable ORACLE_SID as the sid of instance B and connecting with the "sqlplus / as sysdba" command.
This should allow you to connect even if the instance is down, and then you can mount and open it from within sqlplus.
3. If connecting as sysdba also fails, than you should check if a service dedicated to instance B exist. If not, you're instance is not installed probably and should probably start from the top and re-install it.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion.

Comment: No problem. If you this doesn't solve your problem supply more details and we'll try to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your tnsname.ora file has two instance like below..

```
A =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = A)
 )
)

B =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = B)
 )
)
```